# How can I get structure from void* array - C?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I am trying to retrieve value from `void* array` passed to function as argument.

This is what is passed to my function as `void * data` argument:

```
void *sredp[3];
sredp[0] = (void*)buf;
sredp[1] = (void*)(&len);
sredp[2] = (void*)(&ri);
```

source: https://github.com/kamailio/kamailio/blob/master/udp_server.c#L481

For the dereferencing of first two fields I am using this code:

```
int my_fnc(void *data)
{
        str *obuf;
        obuf = (str*)data;
}
```

`str` is internal type of Kamailio server (http://www.asipto.com/pub/kamailio-devel-guide/#c05str).

I am wondering how can I dereference `ri` field from `void *data`. I am trying to do this like this:

```
int my_fnc(void *data)
{
        struct receive_info * ri;
        ri = (struct receive_info*)(data + 2*sizeof(void*));
}
```

And when I am trying to print `receive_info` structure (https://github.com/sipwise/kamailio/blob/4ee1c6a799713b999aac23de74b26badbe06d0aa/ip_addr.h#L132) it seems to giving me some data but I have no idea if theese are just some random bytes from memory or it is correct data that I should retrieve.

So my question is if I am doing it right and if there is another/better way to reach my goal?

Comment: The casts to/from `void *` and other data pointer types are useless and confusing, and should be removed.

Comment: The answer depends on what you are passing to `my_fnc`. I suggest to change the signature to `void my_fnc(void** data_ptr)`.

Comment: It is not possible to pointer arithmetic on `void *` type. You pointer arithmetic by casting to a `char *` instead.

Comment: @harper I am expecting argument passed to event that I am listening on like you can see in this line: https://github.com/kamailio/kamailio/blob/master/udp_server.c#L485

So it is `(void*)`.

Comment: @unwind In this case it is not the matter of choice. I am getting this void array from the core of Kamailio server which I cannot change.

Comment: @Cockootec No, the casts really are unnecessary and should be removed. I'd say it to whoever wrote the code you linked to too, if that was posted here. :) There's no need to cast a data pointer to (or from!) `void *` in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` in `my_fnc` has to be treated as `void**` to be able to extract the real data.

```
int my_fnc(void *data)
{
   void** sredp = (void**)data;
   str* obuf = (str*)srdep[0];

   // The pointer that contains len can be obtained from srdep[1]
   // The pointer that contains ri can be obtained from srdep[2]
}
```

Here's a simple program that illustrates that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void* data)
{
   void** realData = (void**)data;
   void* p1 = realData[0];
   void* p2 = realData[1];
   void* p3 = realData[2];

   printf("sredp[0]: %p\n", p1);
   printf("sredp[1]: %p\n", p2);
   printf("sredp[2]: %p\n", p3);

   int a1 = *(int*)p1;
   float a2 = *(float*)p2;
   double a3 = *(double*)p3;

   printf("a1: %d\n", a1);
   printf("a2: %f\n", a2);
   printf("a3: %lf\n", a3);
}

int main()
{
   int a1 = 10;
   float a2 = 20.0f;
   double a3 = 40.0;
   void *sredp[3];
   sredp[0] = &a1;
   sredp[1] = &a2;
   sredp[2] = &a3;

   printf("sredp[0]: %p\n", sredp[0]);
   printf("sredp[1]: %p\n", sredp[1]);
   printf("sredp[2]: %p\n", sredp[2]);

   foo(sredp);
}
```

Sample output from running the program:

```
sredp[0]: 0x28ac2c
sredp[1]: 0x28ac28
sredp[2]: 0x28ac20
sredp[0]: 0x28ac2c
sredp[1]: 0x28ac28
sredp[2]: 0x28ac20
a1: 10
a2: 20.000000
a3: 40.000000
```

Comment: Thanks. All your, blue112's and mine solution give me the same output. I don't know how the right output should look like so I am trust your example program which shows that the data I am retrieving should be right data and not some random bytes from memory.

Comment: Making `foo` accept `void **` would cut out one level of ick

Comment: @MattMcNabb `foo` was meant o mimic `my_fnc`. I suspect `my_fnc` is a callback function whose signature needs to confirm to a callback mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do pointer arithmetic with void* in C. It would require it to use sizeof(void), which doesn't really exists.

The problem is in your function signature :

> int my_fnc(void *data)

Your pointer is not a void*, it's a void**.
So cast it before using it :

```
void** d = (void**) data;
ri = (struct receive_info*)(d + 2);
```

This will use a sizeof(void*), which is a standard pointer size.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic with `void*` should be prohibited! Usually a `+1` to a `void*` adds one byte. Your D `data+2` is two bytes off the pointer data. When you assume that data points to an array of pointers you will get the third and fourth byte of the first pointer mixed with the next.

Comment: Actually, there is no pointer arithmetic with `void *` in C standard.

Comment: @blue112 I tried it and it generates other I think random data. In the other words I still not sure if these data are the data I am trying to retrieve...

Comment: Edited my answer to consider your comments.

Comment: @blue112 when I am trying to print it my way and print it your way it seems that its the same.

Comment: Yes. `(d+2)` is a pointer to a pointer you want to get. So, you should dereference it. `ri = (struct receive_info*)*(d + 2);` or better `ri = (struct receive_info*)d[2];`